# Why can't I run a Custom build using a 2 week old revision in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I have a problem restoring the artifacts of an old build in TeamCity v10.0 with git for VCS.

I have a collection of projects, all of which depend on a central one called 'infra'. The other projects have artifact dependencies (not snapshots) so whenever infra builds, the dependent projects get triggered to use the latest set of artifacts from infra i.e. include files, libs etc.

I had a stable version of infra about 2 weeks ago which was used for building the dependent projects. Unfortunately I didn't pin it and the cleanup process deleted its artifacts, though the history is still there. In the meantime infra has moved on and there are 20 or so commits beyond that stable version.

If I try to rebuild it to get the artifacts back, using Actions -> Re-run with the same revisions... I'm shown the correct commit in the Changes -> Include changes drop-down, but the VCS root below that shows the very latest commit. If I go ahead with the build I'll get a build using the latest commit and not the one I asked for or was in the original build.

What's weird is that if I select a more recent commit, it is correctly selected. It's only if I go back more than a few days that the VCS snaps to the latest commit. This also applies more generally for all projects where trying a custom build with a commit older than about a week forces me to use the latest commit.

I can't work out why and there's no obvious relation to artifact dependencies, pinned builds or any cleanup interval.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using git? If so, did someone squash or similar? Meaning, is the changeset actually still present in your repository?

Comment: Yep using git and the commit is still in there. It's also on master so no obvious complications with branches etc. I've also disabled the artifact dependencies in case that unblocks it, with no effect.